# How to correct url in vuejs?

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, axios

I send a request using axios to **http://localhost:8000/api/residence** after that i show the result in my page when i want to move to another page by clicking on button i got the wrong url(current url + url of request axios) like this**(http://localhost:8080/http://127.0.0.1:8000/residence/6)** how i can fix this issue.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4" v-for="r in res.data">
   <div class="card-body">
     <h4 class="card-title">{{r.nom}} <br></h4>
   </div>
   <div>
    <router-link :to="'/residence/' + r.id" class="btn btn-outline-primary 
btn-sm btt">Full info</router-link> 
   </div>           
 </div>

axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/residence?page=' + page)
.then(response => {   
  this.res = response.data.data;
 });
```

Comment: We would need to see some code.

Comment: does your button have a leading `/` in the href attribute ? `href="/http://127.0.0.1:8000/residence/6"`.

Answer (score 1):

the form :

```
<form @submit.prevent="addproperty()">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Property Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="property-title" class="form-control" placeholder="Property Title"required v-model="property_title">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                        </form>
```

The Url:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                property_title:null,

            }
        },
        methods: {
            addproperty() {

            axios.post('addproperty',{title: this.property_title});
                this.$router.push('/properties_list')
            },

        },
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Put the description of your answer to help the user understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

Both localhost and 127.0.0.1 are the same. Both of them resolves to your application when accessed either with `localhost:8000` or `127.0.0.1:8000`.

Its not necessary to provide the base-URL in `axios.get` function unless you're fetching data from other sites.

`axios.get('/api/residence?page='+page)` will work fine.

If you need to change the base URL for all the axios calls, you can change the base URL using `axios.defaults.baseURL`. This would be helpful if you want to prepend `/api/` to all of your requests by default.